# How to Pause Background Music When Home Button Pressed

Tags: android

I need to know this so I can remove the exit option.

```
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) { 
if (hasFocus) { 
 mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.theme); 
 mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) { 
if (hasFocus) { 
 Static mediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.theme); 
mp.start();
mp.setLooping(true);

}}
```

Use this to override homekey.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the home button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                     
    mp.pause();
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: On this Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); mediaplayer.pause(); 
 I got an error that said, (btw using AIDE), Unknown enitity mediaplayer

Comment: @user1877134 Upcase the letter P in `mediaplayer.pause();` so it's the same as your declaration of `mediaPlayer`.